# Resetting elapsed time and setInterval in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, reset

I've worked through this code and am close to what I want, yet two small details are missing. The function measures elapsed time between two events and stops after 3 runs.

I would like to have the time reset after each keypress event. In my research I found this question: [Mesure a Reaction Time in ms on a JSP webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021305/mesure-a-reaction-time-in-ms-on-a-jsp-webpage) but it wasn't of much help for the resetting.

Also I would like to change the text of my div every 2 seconds automatically when no key is pressed and get the elapsed time of 2000 then.

Is this possible in some way? I've tried setInterval but didn't succeed.

```
var t1;
var counter=0;
var teststim = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"];

$(function(){
    t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        var t2 = (new Date()).getTime();
        var reac = t2 - t1;
        counter++;
        if (e.keyCode == 97 || e.keyCode == 108) {
            $("#stimuli").text(teststim[Math.floor(Math.random() * teststim.length)]);
        };
        if (counter == 3) {
            confirm("It's over!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: "*every 2 seconds automatically*"... Tried with `setInterval` ?

Comment: setInterval seems right to me.  Call the function every 2 seconds, and if a key is pressed clear the timer and reset it to 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't measure reaction time, but it's a working example of `setInterval` / `clearInterval`.

```
updateText = function(){
    $("body").append( $("<p></p>").html(Date()))
}
timer = setInterval( updateText, 2000 )
$(document).keypress(function(){
    clearInterval( timer)
         $("body").append( $("<p></p>").html("Keypress at " + Date() ))
    timer = setInterval( updateText, 2000 )

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KHaaL/

Comment: thank you. This is great. Any idea where I should invoke my counter? Transferred to your example, I want to count the number of "date prints" on the screen, regardless of whether it was key induced or in the interval. This would make my day...

Comment: Fixed the counter myself: just made separate counters for regular runs and key events. This worked. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Set `t1` to the current time after you measure the reaction time.

```
var reac = t2 - t1;
t1 = t2;
```